# How to install Xamarin.Forms 4.0 templates in VS 2019 RC?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using VS 2019 RC (16.0.0 RC).
This Xamarin Blog article [Xamarin Forms 4.0 Preview](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-4-0-preview/) refers the VS project templates:

> *To quickly get started, if you’re using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, [download and install our template pack](https://aka.ms/xf-shell-templates) that has updated templates based on Shell.*

I've downloaded and installed the vsix. It installed with success to VS 2019. 
However when I try to create a new project, still only the original Xamarin.Forms 3.6 templates appear.

**Question**

What am I missing? I am not a template guru, how can I utilize those templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed steps in that blog:

1. Download and install `Visual Studio 2019 Preview`.
2. Download and install the [vsix](https://aka.ms/xf-shell-templates).
3. When I **create a new Project** => **Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)** => Config your project Name and then press **Create** => I find a new template called **Shell**.

Here is a screenShot of **Shell**:

[image]

4. Press **OK** and you can get a project with **Shell** template.

Note:  I didn't find `shell` Template When creating `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` project.