# Can't install vsix to Visual Studio 2019 - Android Device Manager has a lower version than required by Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed with Xamarin. I'm trying to get Shell to show up in the project templates. I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929894/how-to-install-xamarin-forms-4-0-templates-in-vs-2019-rc) as a guide. But when I install the vsix file, it fails with the error message: Installation of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Android.DeviceManager failed. The extension has a lower version than required by Visual Studio.  Please install the extension from Visual Studio Installer instead.

Where in the Visual Studio Installer is the Android Device Manager? I've installed all the Mobile Development tools and all updates....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is obsolete - it describes something you needed to do in a *Preview* version of VS 2019.

---

In VS Installer, select Workload "Mobile development with .NET".

I was unable to find any Microsoft doc that tells you to simply do that!

---

I don't recall whether you still need to also do this step:

[Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows).

After installing the Workload mentioned above, restart VS. See if the menu item mentioned below is there. If so, try to make a sample app - maybe this "Android SDK" step is no longer needed - the Workload might set everything up.

---

Then Android Device Manager will be at menu Tools / Android / Android Device Manager.

[Menu location documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows#launching-the-device-manager).